# Send email at automated times stored in database

Tags: php, sql, automation

For a project at university I have a requirement to send an email to a list of users, at a certain time each day, between certain dates.

The times required to send the emails are stored in a MySQL database like so:

```
Name      | Email address     | Start     | Finish   | Time
User 1    | user@example.com  | 20111008  | 20111015 | 1630
User 2    | bob2@example.com  | 20111011  | 20111025 | 0900
etc, etc
```

We're using mostly PHP on a linux-based server.

The text for the email to everyone will be identical. It is probable that many users will have the same time specified, but I can figure out how to make the calls unique.

Is there a way that, when the data is inserted into the database, I can create a scheduled job to run at the specified time every day? And to delete said scheduled job if it is past the finish data? I can figure out what the script needs to be, but I'm not sure what technologies to use to create/run/delete the scheduled job.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to run cron your server.
here is some useful document.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Answer (score 1):

the best option would be cron jobs

here is some documentation:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

hope that helps!